# report builder percentage is coming wrong

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

iam using report builder this is my first report , though iam able to create there is one column in col chart report which is shooting high like 70% even though data is not there

here is my col chart report
[image]

my data from sql server come likes this

```
Start_Date  Total   Required
2017-04-01 00:00:00.000 6   6
2017-05-01 00:00:00.000 12  11
2017-06-01 00:00:00.000 3   3
2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 3   3
2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 7   7
2017-09-01 00:00:00.000 6   6
2017-10-01 00:00:00.000 3   3
2017-11-01 00:00:00.000 3   3
2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 3   3
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 15  14
2018-02-01 00:00:00.000 13  13
2018-03-01 00:00:00.000 24  21
```

[image]

```
on x axis we have =FORMAT(CDATE(Fields!Start_Date.Value), "MMM-yy") & vbcrlf & Fields!Total.Value

on y axis we have =IIF(Fields!Total.Value = 0, 1, IIF(Sum(Fields!Required.Value) / Sum(Fields!Total.Value) = 1, 0, (Sum(Fields!Total.Value) - Sum(Fields!Required.Value)) / Sum(Fields!Total.Value)))
```

i deally for june month there is no change we should get as 0 but its coming 70% iam confused can you please help me out here

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this using the given information, I received the correct output (June shows 0, as well as the other months all have the correct values; May, Jan, and Mar in your screenshot are incorrect, as are the numbers displayed under those month names). You have 2 parameters shown in the first screenshot though - do those parameters affect your dataset at all?

Comment: june should be 0 as total and required are same , where total and required are different then that bar is shown like may jan march

Comment: Yes, but the percentages shown in your screenshot (as well as the numbers under the month on the x-axis) do not seem to be correct based on the data given and the expressions used. May should be 8.333%, January should be 6.667% and March should be 12.5%. That is the output that I get using the given data as a dataset and using the exact expressions given, so the only way I can see you getting something different is if your dataset is different, which would also likely explain why you are getting 70% for June instead of 0.